# Wildfly Connection pool with Servlets & Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, threadpool, connection-pooling

We have an web application which uses servlets, jsps and Threads which is a MultiThreaded application. We use JDK1.8, Wildfly server 8.2.I have created a ContextListener as shown below to get the connection object using JNDI datasource. Is this correct way of getting the connection using Connection Pool?

AppContextListener.java

```
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{

  /* (non-Javadoc)    
   * @see javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)    
   */    
  @Override    
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)
  {        
    ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();  
    DBConnectionManager dbManager = (DBConnectionManager)ctx.getAttribute("DBManager");      
    dbManager.closeConnection();  
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)  
   * @see   javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)  
   */  
  @Override  
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)
  {  
    ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();  
    String jndiName = ctx.getInitParameter("JNDI");  

    //create database connection from context parameters and set it to context
    DBConnectionManager dbManager = new DBConnectionManager(jndiName);
    ctx.setAttribute("DBManager", dbManager);  
  }
}
```

DBConnectionManager.java

```
public class DBConnectionManager
{
  private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(DBConnectionManager.class);
  private static Connection conn;
  private String jndiName;

  public DBConnectionManager(String jndiName) {
    this.jndiName = jndiName;
    try {
       Context ctx = new InitialContext();
       DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(this.jndiName);
       conn = ds.getConnection();
       conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
       logger.error("[DBConnectionManager.DBConnectionManager]Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }    
  }

  public static Connection getConnection(){
     return conn; 
  }

  public void closeConnection(){
     if(conn != null){
       try {
          conn.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
          logger.error("[DBConnectionManager.closeConnection]Exception: "+e.getMessage());
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Whenever I need a connection object I call the static method getConnection(). Seems I am not achieving Connection pool using this way. How should I get the connection to achieve Connection pool?

My server will be running for more than 12 hours and When I try to reload the messages sent table system will throw the below exceptions which is causing due to Threads. How can I solve this?

```
TxConnectionListener:380 - IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@bed9492[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@5df6b58b connection handles=1 lastUse=1462985106208 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@1299562a mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@3a1d6b71[pool=RDTSDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@4b534943[connectionListener=bed9492 connectionManager=f7fbabb warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options jndiName=java:jboss/RDTSDS] txSync=null]
javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Unexpected error
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:644)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:610)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:1640)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:1267)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:467)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.beans.ReconcileInfo.getNextMessage(ReconcileInfo.java:493)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.beans.GroupInfo.sendMessage(GroupInfo.java:818)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.GroupSendThread.send(GroupSendThread.java:114)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.GroupSendThread.run(GroupSendThread.java:68)
 Caused by: java.lang.ThreadDeath
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:850)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.HttpDequeue.stopThread(HttpDequeue.java:944)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.HttpDequeue.clearLocks(HttpDequeue.java:418)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.HttpDequeue.run(HttpDequeue.java:404)
```

Exception in Server log :

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$WildFlyLocalMCF] (NRG) Queued thread: ECOG-ACRIN: java.lang.Throwable: Queued thread: ECOG-ACRIN
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:224) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.lock(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:373)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.tryLock(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:388)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:147)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareCall(WrappedConnection.java:589)
```

I am stuck in this issue since 15 days. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check you code in this part HttpDequeue and the thread implementation, you can use this guide to replace the Thread.stop() implementation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ThreadDeath
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:850)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.HttpDequeue.stopThread(HttpDequeue.java:944)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.HttpDequeue.clearLocks(HttpDequeue.java:418)
    at com.ctsu.rdts.app.HttpDequeue.run(HttpDequeue.java:404)
```

> An instance of ThreadDeath is thrown in the victim thread when the
>   (deprecated) Thread.stop() method is invoked.
>
> An application should catch instances of this class only if it must
>   clean up after being terminated asynchronously. If ThreadDeath is
>   caught by a method, it is important that it be rethrown so that the
>   thread actually dies.
>
> The top-level error handler does not print out a message if
>   ThreadDeath is never caught.